# Alocação de memória com malloc()

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória, alocação, malloc

**Dúvida 1**: Os `pont` deveriam reservar um bloco de memoria para 1 inteiro o que foi pedido no `malloc()`, mas ele reserva *32 bytes* ou seja um bloco de memoria para 8 inteiros.
Porque ele faz isso?

**Dúvida 2**: Se eu faço um `for` indo ate a X posições ele consegue 'invadir' as posições do bloco alocado por `pont2`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int *pont1 = malloc(sizeof(int));

    int *pont2 = malloc(sizeof(int));

    printf("Valor de pont1 (endereco de memoria alocada por pont1) = %d\n", pont1);

    printf("Endereco de pont1 = %d\n", &pont1);

    printf("\nValor de pont2 (endereco de memoria alocada por pont2) = %d\n", pont2);

    printf("Endereco de pont2 = %d\n", &pont2);

    long int endMemoriaAlocadoPont1 = &*pont1;
    long int endMemoriaAlocadoPont2 = &*pont2;

    int numeroBytes = (int) (endMemoriaAlocadoPont2 - endMemoriaAlocadoPont1);

    printf("\nMemoria alocada de cada pont = %d bytes\n", numeroBytes); //printa 32 Bytes

    
/*1°duvida: Os 'pont' deveriam reservar um bloco de memoria para 1 inteiro q foi o q pedi no malloc,
mas ele reserva 32 bytes ou seja um bloco de memoria para 8 inteiros, Porque ele faz isso?*/

    for(int i=0; i< 8; i++){ //digitando os valores no bloco de *pont1

        printf("Digite um valor para pont1[%d] = ",i);

        scanf("%d", &pont1[i]);

        printf("endereco de memoria de pont1[%d] = %d\n",i , &pont1[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i< 8; i++){

        printf("%d  ", pont1[i]);//printando valores do bloco q foi alocado por *pont1
    }

    printf("\nbloco de memoria alocado por *pont1 vai de %d ate %d\n", &pont1[0], &pont1[7]);

    /*2° duvida: Se eu faco um for indo ate a X posicoes ele consegue 'invadir' as pocicoes do
    bloco alocado por pont2, segue abaixo:*/

    for(int i=0; i< 10; i++){ //indo ate a 9º posicao, 'invadindo' 2 posicoes do bloco alocado por *pont2

        printf("Digite um valor para pont1[%d] = ",i);
        scanf("%d", &pont1[i]);
    }

    printf("valor de pont2[0] = %d\n", pont2[0]);//vai printar o valor digitado em 'pont1[8] do for acima

    printf("valor de pont2[1] = %d\n", pont2[1]);//vai printar o valor digitado em 'pont1[9] do for acima

    return 0;

}
```

Segue abaixo output do programa: [image: resultado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse é o protótipo de malloc()

```
    void *malloc(size_t size);
```

E eis o que diz a documentação em português em [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/malloc?view=msvc-160) sobre `malloc()`:

`size` Bytes para alocar

E sobre o valor retornado

> malloc retorna um ponteiro void para o espaço alocado ou NULL se não
> houver memória suficiente disponível. Para retornar um ponteiro para
> um tipo diferente de void , use uma conversão de tipo no valor de
> retorno. O espaço de armazenamento apontado pelo valor retornado é
> garantido para ser sutilmente alinhado para armazenamento de qualquer
> tipo de objeto que tenha um requisito de alinhamento menor ou igual ao
> alinhamento fundamental. (No Visual C++, o alinhamento fundamental é o
> alinhamento necessário para um double ou 8 bytes. No código que tem
> como destino plataformas de 64 bits, é 16 bytes.) Use _aligned_malloc
> para alocar armazenamento para objetos que têm um requisito de
> alinhamento maior — por exemplo, os tipos de SSE __m128 e e os __m256
> tipos declarados usando __declspec(align( n )) onde n é maior que 8.
> Se o tamanho for 0, malloc alocará um item de comprimento zero no heap
> e retornará um ponteiro válido para esse item. Sempre verifique o
> retorno de malloc, mesmo se a quantidade de memória solicitada for
> pequena. **Comentários** A função malloc aloca um bloco de memória de pelo
> menos bytes de tamanho . O bloco pode ser maior que o tamanho em bytes
> devido ao espaço necessário para informações de alinhamento e
> manutenção. malloc define errno como ENOMEM se uma alocação de memória
> falhar ou se a quantidade de memória solicitada excede _HEAP_MAXREQ.
> Para obter informações sobre esse e outros códigos de erro, consulte
> errno, _doserrno, _sys_errlist e _sys_nerr. O código de inicialização
> usa malloc para alocar armazenamento para as variáveis _environ, envp
> e argv .

Do manual [POSIX.1-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) sobre `malloc()` tem essa nota:

> The malloc() function shall allocate unused space for an object whose size in bytes is specified by size and whose value is unspecified.
>
> **The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to malloc() is unspecified**. The pointer returned if the allocation
> succeeds shall be suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a
> pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object
> in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly freed or
> reallocated). Each such allocation shall yield a pointer to an object
> disjoint from any other object. The pointer returned points to the
> start (lowest byte address) of the allocated space. If the space
> cannot be allocated, a null pointer shall be returned. If the size of
> the space requested is 0, the behavior is implementation-defined: the
> value returned shall be either a null pointer or a unique pointer

A parte em negrito é o que importa no seu caso. Em português:

> A ordem e continuidade do espaço alocado por chamadas sucessivas de
> `malloc()` é indefinida.

Isso quer dizer que você não pode fazer contas e tirar conclusões sobre esses endereços e essas diferenças, como fez em seu programa.

#### De volta ao programa

#### Sobre essas linhas

```
    long int endMemoriaAlocadoPont1 = &*pont1;
    long int endMemoriaAlocadoPont2 = &*pont2;
```

Use nomes mais curtos quando estiver testando algo...

& é o contrário de *. Tanto faz isso como escrever

```
    long int endMemoriaAlocadoPont2 = &*pont2;
    endMemoriaAlocadoPont2 = &*&*&*&*&*&*pont2;
    endMemoriaAlocadoPont2 = pont2;
```

> dúvida1: Os pont deveriam reservar um bloco de memoria para 1 inteiro o que foi pedido no malloc(), mas ele reserva 32 bytes ou seja um bloco de memoria para 8 inteiros.
> Porque ele faz isso?

Não, o sistema não faz isso. O valor alocado é o que foi passado como argumento. Pode não ter mesmo sido alocado, mas você não testou afinal.

> duvida2: Se eu faço um for indo ate a X posições ele consegue 'invadir' as posições do bloco alocado por pont2?

Sim. Dentro do espaço alocado para seus dados. Se o valor apontado estiver fora do seu espaço vai cancelar o programa com a popular exceção "Access Violation"

#### Exemplo

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

    int* pont1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *pont1 = 4;
    printf("Endereco de pont1 = %p\n", &pont1);
    printf("pont1 aponta para = %p\n", pont1);
    printf("e o valor la = %d\n", *pont1);

    int* pont2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *pont2 = 64;
    printf("\nEndereco de pont2 = %p\n", &pont2);
    printf("pont2 aponta para = %p\n", pont2);
    printf("e o valor la = %d\n", *pont2);

    int* outro = malloc(sizeof(int));
    memcpy( outro, pont1, sizeof(pont1));
    printf("valor de '*outro' com o endereco copiado de pont1 = %d\n\n", *outro);

    outro  = 1024;
    //printf("valor de '*outro' com o endereco 1024 = %d\n\n", *outro);
    long int endMemoriaAlocadoPont1 = &*pont1;
    printf("Endereco 2: %p\n", endMemoriaAlocadoPont1);
    endMemoriaAlocadoPont1 = &*pont1;
    printf("Endereco 2: %p\n", endMemoriaAlocadoPont1);
    endMemoriaAlocadoPont1 = &*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*pont1;
    printf("Endereco 2: %p\n", endMemoriaAlocadoPont1);
    return 0;

}
```

**É praticamente o seu programa e mostra**

```
Endereco de pont1 = 012FF85C
pont1 aponta para = 01626CD0
e o valor la = 4

Endereco de pont2 = 012FF850
pont2 aponta para = 01625870
e o valor la = 64
valor de '*outro' com o endereco copiado de pont1 = 4

Endereco 2: 01626CD0
Endereco 2: 01626CD0
Endereco 2: 01626CD0
```

Em especial atente para essas linhas:

```
   int* outro = malloc(sizeof(int));
    memcpy( outro, pont1, sizeof(pont1));
    printf("valor de '*outro' com o endereco copiado de pont1 = %d\n\n", *outro);

    outro  = 1024;
    //printf("valor de '*outro' com o endereco 1024 = %d\n\n", *outro);
```

`outro` é um ponteiro para `int` e foi alocado via malloc(). Não é nada saudável no uso geral mas como exemplo se pode usar `memcpy()` e copiar um endereço lá para ver o que tem na memória naquele endereço.

E o programa mostra lá o valor `4` como esperado, já que é o que tem em `*pont1`.
Mas se tirar o comentário do segundo `printf()` e tentar ver o valor do endereço 1024...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E `0x400` no popular decimal é 1024...

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro: essa conta usa um conceito errado para ver o espaço alocado, nada impede de alocar um objeto em uma distancia enorme de outro, então medir a distância entre eles não dará, garantidamente, o tamanho alocado. Mesmo que neste caso tenha dado certo, não confie nessa informação.

Segundo: ele não aloca espaço para 8 inteiros, ele aloca 32 bytes, a quantidade de inteiros que cabe aí depende de onde está rodando, não use essa medida que ela é errada, pode até ser que neste caso foi assim, mas usar essa medida ensina errado.

A maneira como a alocação é feita é um detalhe de implementação do alocador, você não precisa saber disso na maioria das situações. Em alguns casos onde precisa gerenciar a memória de forma extrema aí pode ser útil saber e tentar fazer algo, e provavelmente será usar um alocador mais econômico, pagando o preço que tem nele, tudo é escolha, é *tradeoff*.

É comum a alocação em memória dinâmica só ser feita em tamanhos mínimos então os alocadores são otimizados para isto. Tem algumas vantagens para o alocador usar certas estratégias para ter algum ganho.

Geralmente quando tem que alocar menos de 32 bytes o objeto nem deveria ser alocado dinamicamente.

Não confie em comportamentos visíveis quando está programando, principalmente em C. Para usar algo tem que ler toda documentação, aprender todos detalhes e usar conforme aprendeu, não com o que viu. Certos comportamentos acontecem por coincidência.

Então mesmo que tenha alocado 32 bytes e o inteiro tenha 4 bytes de tamanho, usar 8 *slots* em um lugar que foi reservado só para um inteiro pode dar certo ou não, nesse caso deu, mas se o compilador usar outro alocador, se compilar para outra arquitetura, já não funciona mais. Códigos precisam funcionam sempre (a não ser que tenha um requisito muito específico, mas que já deve ser um erro também).

A segunda dúvida na verdade explica isso melhor. Você pode acessar a memória livremente, não dá erro, mas possivelmente dará um resultado indesejado, e o pior que pode acontecer é dar o resultado esperado, porque quem acredita no que vê em vez de ler a documentação vai achar que está certo, mas apenas funcionou, ficou assim:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Ponteiros existem para acessar endereços de memória, só isso, não ache que ele faz qualquer outra coisa, não pense que tem algo a ver com a alocação, inclusive porque a única alocação garantida é de 4 bytes (nesse caso, poderia ser 2 ou 8 em outros, ou até outro tamanho em alguma arquitetura esquisita ou alguma técnica maluca). Use como quiser e obtenha qualquer resultado que esteja lá ou mude onde quiser. Se fizer tudo certo o resultado será oque espera, se não fizer certo poderá dar o resultado esperado ou não. Se fizer errado e tiver interação externa pode abrir um belo buraco de segurança.

Comment: Na segunda duvida é o seguinte: O malloc no *pont1 alocou 32bytes ou seja nesse bloco alocado cabe 8 inteiros, de pont1[0] ate pont1[7]... Porem no ultimo FOR eu digito valores ate a posicao 9 posicao -> pont1[8] = 1111 e pont1[9] = 2222 e nao da 'erro'. O bloco de *pont1 so vai ate a posicao 7 o q vi é que os valores de pont1[8] e pont1[9] 'invade' o bloco alocado por *pont2 como da pra ver eu print o valor de pont2[0] e pont2[1] e sao 1111 e 2222 respectivamente.